# CSS - if div is empty, display content

Tags: html, css

Is it possible to create a conditional div display depending on another div's content being present or not? **I'm looking for a CSS only solution.**

I've used something like this before:

```
.myClass:empty:before {
    content: 'content added to empty div';
}
```

- to add content to an empty div. But since there is no way to create hyperlinks in the created pseudo-content, I'm looking for another way.

So let's assume my div structure is as follows:

```
<div class="div1"></div>
<div class="div2">This should be displayed</div>
```

Is it possible to do a css trick to display div2 if div1 is empty; but hide it if div1 has content?

Feel free to restructure the div hierarchy, what I'm looking for does not depend on the current div structure.

Looking for ideas. Thank you.

Answer (score 8):

I'd suggest:

```css
/* hiding the div.div2 element (and its content)
   if it's the next element-sibling of div.div1: */
div.div1 + div.div2 {
    display: none;
}

/* selecting the div.div2 element which is the next
   element-sibling of an empty (div.div1:empty)
   div.div1 element: */
div.div1:empty + div.div2 {
    display: block;
}
```

```css
/* hiding the div.div2 element (and its content)
       if it's the next element-sibling of div.div1: */
div.div1 + div.div2 {
  display: none;
}

/* selecting the div.div2 element which is the next
       element-sibling of an empty (div.div1:empty)
       div.div1 element: */

div.div1:empty + div.div2 {
  display: block;
}

div.div1 {
  border: 1px solid #f00;
  color: #f00;
}

div.div2 {
  color: #0f0;
  border: 1px solid #0f0;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
}
```

```html
<div class="div1"></div>
<div class="div2">This should be displayed</div>

<div class="div1">This is 'div.div1' (it has content)</div>
<div class="div2">This should not be displayed</div>
```

Answer (score 7):

use css- next element selecor

```
.div1:empty + div{
    content: 'content added to empty div';
}
```

Comment: "*since there is no way to create hyperlinks in the created pseudo-content, I'm looking for another way*"

Comment: Oh yes, but the + might work to display:block the secondary element!

Answer (score 2):

Thank you for the quick answers. Based on Alexis Peters' answer, I've created this one which worked like a charm. Putting it down for future reference:

```
div2 {
    display: none;
}

.div1:empty + .div2{
    display: block;
}
```

An explanation is (for explorers like me) CSS above says "set div2 to not display. If any .div2 follows an empty .div1 then set display to block".

Cheers.